# suppress errors in trace emulator

Tags: plutus, plutustx, emulator

I would like to suppress this error. How can I do that ?

Slot 00013: *** CONTRACT LOG: "PassingTest [TEST_TAG:3] -- caught error: WalletContractError (ValidationError (ScriptFailure (EvaluationError [] "CekEvaluationFailure: An error has occurred:  User error:\nThe machine terminated part way through evaluation due to overspending the budget.\nThe budget when the machine terminated was:\n({ cpu: 6259676882\n| mem: -3722\n})\nNegative numbers indicate the overspent budget; note that this only indicatessthe budget that was needed for the next step, not to run the program to completion.")))"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different TraceConfig. See here for example https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/blob/20ac87dc4d0bd969840168bd84c063f3a6f78887/plutus-contract/src/Plutus/Trace/Emulator.hs#L239